# Insert multiple html cells in a single html table row

Tags: c#, html

Insert multiple html cells in a single html table row. The below stated code adds the cells in a single row.

```
HtmlTable MyTable = new HtmlTable();
                        HtmlTableRow row = new HtmlTableRow();
                        HtmlTableCell cell = new HtmlTableCell();

                        cell = (new HtmlTableCell
                        {
                            InnerHtml = Text + ":",
                            Align = "Left"
                        });
                        row.Cells.Add(cell);

                        cell = (new HtmlTableCell
                        {
                            InnerHtml = "Minimum" + " " + "33" + "%",
                            Align = "Right"
                        });
                        row.Cells.Add(cell);


                        cell = (new HtmlTableCell
                        {
                            InnerHtml = "Maximum" + " " + "34" + "%",
                            Align = "Right"
                        });
                        row.Cells.Add(cell);
                        MyTable.Rows.Add(selectedFeatures);
```

**The result is like :-**

[image]

**But I want it to be like :-**

[image]

Comment: Try creating several rows, and not adding the cells to the same one row.

Comment: I have to add cell in the same row.

Comment: then you will get your data in the same row, and it's not what you want

Comment: From what I understand in html you are looking for rowspan. So these cells above should each be on a different row, and the other rows in the table should have rowspan

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to achieve. 
 Cells in a row belong to different columns. Looks like you either want text in multiple rows or all the text in the same cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a single HTMLTableRow object and adding cells to it.

```
row.Cells.Add(cell);
```

This will add a new Cell to the same row. What you need is a new Row object for every row, or re-initialize the same Row object, for every new row.As yoy have done for Table Cells.

```
row = new HtmlTableRow();
```